# Swift mailer triggers fatal error;

Tags: php, swiftmailer

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message
>   "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. fb9sm57232081wid.2 -
>   gsmtp "' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('530 5.7.0
>   Must ...', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(245):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM:
>   executeCommand('MAIL FROM: _doMailFromCommand('sophie3394@gm...')
>
> ## 4 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444):
>
> Swift_Transport_AbstractSmt in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   on line 386

This is the error caused by the following code:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");

require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 25)
    ->setUsername('sophie3394@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('xxxx');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('sophie3394@gmail.com' => 'ABC'))
    ->setTo(array('sophie3394@gmail.com'))
    ->setBody('This is a test mail.');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

What are the steps to resolve this error?

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
>   [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable
>   it when you configured PHP? #1899472503]' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:259 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(64):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(80):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Mail.php(26):
>   Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line
>   259

Answer (score 10):

Change the port in your code (second argument of the newInstance function) and add a third argument 'ssl'

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
```

It was 25 and the ssl was missing. Swift_SmtpTransport was not using encryption at all and Gmail was complaining about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
```